# extjs 5 window not executing javascript

Tags: extjs5

I have the following function that creates a extjs window. Within the php page is some javascript (for now just a alert("test")) But the alert fails to fire. My understanding is that setting scripts to true should execute script tags.

```
function loadTilePage(tileId){
var url= "page.php";
var yourWindow = new Ext.Window({
    title: 'title',
    autoScroll: true,
    resizable :false,
    height:Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height*.60,
    width:Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width*0.55, 
    loader:{
                url:url,
                scripts: true,
                renderer: 'html',
                autoLoad: true      
    }
}); 
yourWindow.show();
yourWindow.center();
```

}

In the end of the php response is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert("test");</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Injecting script into element markup is blocked by browser. Example:

```
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = '<scr' + 'ipt>alert(123);</scr' + 'ipt>'; // this won't work
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g3dahakr/

You should probably find other way to do that. In Ext JS you can require other JS modules, so IMO instead of using loader it is better to replace page.php with Ext component and load it using require.

Comment: Thanks. I will see if I can figure that out. Still fairly new to ExtJS.